# Change Next.js background color with TailwindCSS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I recently started with Next.js and TailwindCSS and I wanted to change the background of my page. It is probably a really simple thing to do but I can't figure it out how to do. You can't add classes to the `body` tag in Next.js right? I tried to wrap the `Component` in the `_app.tsx` with a `div` but that is also wrapped inside a different `div`, so the background color isn't the full height.

How should I set the background color for my application and is it also possible to overrule it for a single page?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add it using your stylesheet (`styles/globals.css` in case of the [official example](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-tailwindcss)):

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer base {
  body {
    @apply bg-slate-900;
  }
}
```

---

You can also create a [custom document](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-document):

```
// pages/_document.js

import { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'

const Document = () => (
  <Html>
    <Head />
    <body className="bg-slate-900">
      <Main />
      <NextScript />
    </body>
  </Html>
)

export default Document
```

If you want to do it on per-page basis, refer this: [vercel/next.js#12325 (comment)](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/12325#discussioncomment-1116108)

Comment: What would be the nicest solution? The custom Document or the Tailwind layer? I guess if it's pure for styling the layer would be nicest but if you would need also other things the Document would be better. What is your opinion?

Comment: @BartBergmans yeah I also think the same. There is no need to introduce custom document unless you already have it for some other reasons. The tailwind solution doesn't requires creating anything extra. One already has that globals file with `@tailwind` directives. Both are fine in my opinion. And yeah, with custom document, you can also selectively add some classes depending on which page you're rendering. So that might be a plus point for custom document. But it depends completely on your use case.

Comment: How to add classes depending on the page? The documentation about the custom Document is for the entire app right, not depening on what page you are on?

Comment: @BartBergmans Check that link to a comment.